# Why does node not evaluate Math.tan(Math.PI/2) to Infinity but Chrome V8 does?

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, v8, infinity

When running this in a node command-line interface:

```
> Math.tan(Math.PI/2)
16331778728383844
```

But in Chrome:

```
> Math.tan(Math.PI/2)
Infinity
```

Aren't both using the same V8 engine?

Node's result is not even equal to the [maximum "integer" value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t).

Comment: Interesting. What does Math.PI/2 by itself result in in both?

Comment: Same thing!
Node : 1.5707963267948966
Chrome : 1.5707963267948966

Comment: I'm also able to reproduce this issue and I'm stumped as to why it happens. Great question!

Comment: If you take `Math.PI/2` (`1.5707963267948966`) and start plugging it into `Math.tan` with more and more decimal points (starting with `1.57`), the result of `Math.tan(whatever)` becomes `Infinity` at `1.570796326794896` (where the result is `1679930021256638.2`), which is one digit left off

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the [v8 implementation of the `Math` object](https://code.google.com/p/v8/codesearch#v8/trunk/src/math.js&q=tan&sq=package:v8&l=180), you see:

```
function MathTan(x) {
  return MathSin(x) / MathCos(x);
}
```

Indeed, `Math.cos(Math.PI/2)` returns an unusual value in Node as well (in fact, the reciprocal of your unusual `Math.tan` result):

```
> Math.cos(Math.PI/2)
6.123031769111886e-17  // in Chrome, this is 0
```

So, your question reduces to: *Why is `Math.cos(Math.PI/2)` non-zero in Node <=0.10.24?*

This is difficult to answer. The implementation of sine and cosine are supplied by a math-heavy function called [`TrigonometricInterpolation`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/codesearch#v8/trunk/src/math.js&q=math&sq=package:v8&l=221), which relies on a reverse lookup table of 1800 sample values generated by C++ code, code which is itself generated [a Python script when v8 is first installed](https://code.google.com/p/v8/codesearch#v8/trunk/tools/generate-trig-table.py&q=trig&sq=package:v8&l=1).

It is also worth noting, however, that the current trig lookup table code [very recently replaced an older lookup table](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/33b5db090258c2a2dc825659c3ad109bd02110c1), so the current release of Node may not be using the most recent trig lookup table (since new code arrived in v8 on Nov. 22, 2013, but [the only pull from v8 into Node](https://github.com/joyent/node/commits/master/deps/v8/src/math.js) prior to the 0.10.24 release in December 2013 was on Nov 11, 2013, eleven days prior to the change). Chrome probably is using up-to-date code, while current stable Node is using different trigonometric code.

Answer (score 5):

If you type:

```
Math.PI/2
```

Do you get exactly π/2? Nope ;)

Therefore, it can't "accurately" calculate `Math.tan(Math.PI/2)` as being `Infinity` because it doesn't have the precision for `Math.PI/2`.

But in some cases (such as Chrome), the loss of precision is so small that it gets `Infinity` anyway.

To illustrate this, take a look at this console output:

```
Math.PI/2  
> 1.5707963267948966  

Math.tan(1.5707963267948964)  
> 5039790063769915  

Math.tan(1.5707963267948965)  
> Infinity  

Math.tan(1.5707963267948966)  
> Infinity  

Math.tan(1.5707963267948967)  
> -5039790063769915
```

Notice how there are actually two values that result in `Infinity`? That's the inaccuracy.

Comment: "Math.tan(1.5707963267948964) < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER" but
"Math.tan(1.5707963267948964) > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER" . Its the limit that makes it infinity.

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos That may be, but it is irrelevant. `tan` is a float operation, not an integer operation.

Comment: Still in Node : 
> Math.tan(1.570796326794896619231321691639751442098584699687552910487472)

16331778728383844

Comment: How you define Infinity? How your browser? How a powerful server?

Comment: @Ludo `1.570796326794896619231321691639751442098584699687552910487472` still is not exactly `PI/2`. For any engine with high enough precision, you will never get the result of `Infinity` because pi is irrational.

Comment: Doesn't node uses the V8 engine? The same as Chrome's?

Comment: Not with the same settings.

Comment: If node has such a high precision, why doesn't it returns a higher number? 16331778728383844 is far off Number.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE); // nodejs prints 1.7976931348623157e+308

Comment: Exactly. Then shouldn't node's Math.tan(Math.PI/2) be greater than 16331778728383844?

Comment: 1.7976931348623157e+308 means 1.7976931348623157x10^308 ... this number is huge...

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that, server has different settings from a browser.
Infinity is the variable "Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY" but if you check out another variable, the "Number.MAX_INTEGER" my chrome gives:

```
console.log( Number.MAX_INTEGER ) // prints 9007199254740991
```

and 9007199254740991 is smaller than 16331778728383844, so probably chrome decide every number bigger than Number.MAX_INTEGER to be Infinity.

On node js
console.log( Number.MAX_INTEGER ) // prints 1.7976931348623157e+308

Chrome and node js has different up and down limits for Numbers.

To sum up, on **nodejs** `Number.MAX_INTEGER` **is bigger than** `Math.tan(Math.PI/2)`
while **chrome**'s `Number.MAX_INTEGER` **is smaller than** `Math.tan(Math.PI/2)` .

So **nodejs see a number** while **chrome see Infinity**.

Comment: But node's Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER returns undefined

Comment: Thats the point, node has no limit, chrome has a limit, a browser may not do so complex maths. A server may do. Browser execute code that any page gives you. A server execute code that admin want. You can't trust a page but you can trust your admin so u let him do such big and complex maths.

Comment: @Ludo I would think you wouldn't want to limit the size of an integer on a server, whereas on a browser it could open big issues with resource availability.

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos my node gives undefined for  Number.MAX_INTEGER but 1.7976931348623157e+308 for Number.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Probably chrome has 2 variables Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER and Number.MAX_INTEGER for some reason of compatibility probably.

Answer (score 4):

With HEAD version

```
node -v
v0.11.14-pre

node
> Math.tan(Math.PI/2)
Infinity
```

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7852