# Tan of 90 in Google Chrome (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, math

When I evaluate either of these statements in the stable version of Chrome (Version 32.0.1700.107) I get a value that's not `Infinity`.

```
Math.tan(90 * Math.PI / 180)
16331778728383844

Math.tan(Math.PI/2)

16331778728383844
```

What is the root of this problem? I am certain that Math.tan is not reassigned a new value elsewhere in my code.

Comment: This might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536144/why-does-the-google-calculator-give-tan-90-degrees-1-6331779e16

Comment: If I open a console and run either in my Chrome (v37) I get `Infinity` as expected. Try it on a different page to the one with the problem. if there are issues then you must have something else in your code messing things up.

Comment: + 1 to counteract the down votes. The question is valid imho.

Comment: Check out the [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455775/why-does-node-not-evaluate-math-tanmath-pi-2-to-infinity-but-chrome-v8-does).

Comment: @Wooble - That is not related to this question.

Comment: +1, this question is deceptively simple. ) Still it seems to be explained well enough in the linked thread (I've upvoted @Niet's answer, for me it's as close to explanation as can be), hence the 'duplicate' marking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rounding errors. For the same reason `Math.cos(Math.PI/2)` won't give you 0.

UPDATE: Actually it gives you 0 on the latest version of Chrome/Node - but judging from this [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3006), it's actually considered a regression in V8. Still (and it's mentioned in the issue's discussion), `Math.sin/cos` are implementation-dependent approximations, and expecting those to behave in a uniform way all across the board is, sadly, overoptimistic.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting here that in newer version of Chrome, the (perhaps expected) issues to do with floats are actually not present.

This isn't the case in Firefox at the moment, so if you are writing code where this matters, be careful.

[image: Output in Chrome 37]

Comment: No, I can replicate in Firefox and Safari. I think V8 uses a better low level system for this.

Comment: Actually, [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3006) makes me think Chromium has a regression in trigonometric functions (note that the bug is _accepted_). BTW, Node.js also shows the non-zero value for `Math.cos(Math.PI/2)`.

Comment: Just remembered that I don't use the latest version of Node. ) It's `v0.10.23` for me; the answer linked in the comments shows `0` for `0.11` or something like that.

Comment: Yep, I'm on 0.10.25 and get the non Infinity version as well.