# What is 'BigInt' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, numbers

Recently, during a discussion with one of my colleagues, I heard about this new data type in JavaScript - **`BigInt`**.

**Things I know so far:** 
In JavaScript, there is a limitation while using the `Number` type; it cannot safely represent integer values larger than `2 to the power of 53`. This limitation has often forced developers to use inefficient workarounds and third-party libraries to represent much larger numbers. `BigInt` is a new data type intended to fix that.

**Things I want to know:** *(A single question broken into two points for better clarity)*

- In JavaScript, how exactly `BigInt` is implemented / defined?

  - Is it a new data type (similar to `Number`, `Boolean`, etc)?
  - Or implemented similar to existing JavaScript constants like `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, `Infinity`, `-Infinity` etc?

---

**Apart from the above question, something additional to think about:** *(Adding here for reference only)*:
Sometime back, I wrote this SO post about [Can a number in JavaScript ever reach to Infinity in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949608/can-a-number-in-javascript-ever-reach-to-infinity-in-runtime). Is that particular scenario in JavaSscript going to get changed / affected by the introduction of `BigInt`?

Comment: looking on [`mdn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) `BigInt` is a new primitive type

Comment: @jonatjano then same would be the case with all the popular questions on SO with hundreds of upvotes. Google provides a good list of result for all of them. I posted here for the benefit of SO community.

Comment: Important thing I learnt from @certainperformance's answer - ***A `BigInt` is not a `Number` - it is a `BigInt`.***

Answer (score 3):

BigInt is a [finished proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint), at stage 4.

As [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

> BigInt will become the second built-in numeric type in JavaScript.
>
> BigInt is slated to become the first new primitive type added to JavaScript since Symbol in ES2015.

You can see many of the implementation examples on the [proposal page](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint), and for the nitty gritty details, you can read the [proposal specification here](https://tc39.es/proposal-bigint/#sec-bigint-objects).

> Or implemented similar to existing JavaScript constants like MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, Infinity, -Infinity etc?

A BigInt is *not* a `number` - it is a BigInt. (for the existing constants we're familiar with, `typeof Infinity` and `typeof MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and so on, all give `number` in return)

> Is that particular scenario in JavaSscript going to get changed / affected by the introduction of BigInt?

I think that when a number gets too large for a BigInt to handle, it will throw a RangeError (instead of evaluating to a BigInt version of Infinity), at least in V8:

```js
3n ** 3n ** 3n ** 3n
```

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum BigInt size exceeded

See [discussion](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues/174#issuecomment-437471065):

> V8 currently allows 1 billion bits for a BigInt. The limit was 1 million bits for a while, but we found tests that ran into that limit, so we bumped it. We may raise or lower it again if reasons emerge to do so. (Personally, I think it is reasonable to assume that "every implementation will allow at least 1 million bits".)